# Scapy: sending data over TCP layer

Tags: tcp, scapy

I have a basic question about scapy. Does scapy itself take care of sequences and acknowledgement numbers for data transfer or it should be built externally? If externally, then how could that be built? As scapy doesn't do a 3-way handshake by itself and this should be implemented externally.

Aim: aim is to send data with the help of scapy, receive replies and display the data within the received information and data will not be sent directly on TCP layer but an application layer such as http will be used.